# Взятие подстроки,

Tags: javascript, строки

Из кода ниже изымаю подстроку потом вывожу результат в alert. Желаю в одном сообщение выводить оригинал + обработанный результат. Но не работает.

```
var longStr = "murocashicontrozkare";
alert(longStr.substring(5,11) + \nlongStr);
```

Comment: `"\n" + longStr`

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Что происходит, что вы ожидали?

Comment: "не работает" это пустой, белый экран. Хотел бы увидеть в одном диалоговом окне увидеть обработанный результат и оригинал

Comment: @CoffeJava, если откроешь консоль браузера, то увидишь, что в твоем коде синтаксическая ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, вы имеете в виду

```
alert(longStr.substring(5,11) + "\n" + longStr);
```